# Trouble Establishing Communication Between Chrome Extension and API in WhatsApp Environment

Tags: google-chrome-extension, whatsapp

I have a Chrome browser extension that interacts within the WhatsApp environment. I am facing difficulties establishing communication between an API and this extension, particularly regarding input and output data. I need assistance in resolving the data communication issues to ensure seamless interaction. Any guidance or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Error:
Refused to connect to 'http://localhost:5172/api/registerUser_getOne/miId' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self'".

I tried to make an API call and it gives the error mentioned above.